# Fast Image Retrieval

Tags: apache, http, caching, file-io, webserver

I have a website that displays products. Each page displays 16 products and there are around 70,000 products on the site. The HTML for each page is generated using PHP.

Product information is stored within a database. Roughly, the first page of results (if I want to show cheapest items first) would be displayed like this (pseudo code only):

```
// run sql to fetch product titles and image filenames
SELECT itemTitle, itemImageFileName FROM items ORDER BY itemPrice ASC LIMIT 16

// loop through and display items
for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
    echo "<p>$itemTitle</p>";
    echo "<img src=$itemImageFileName height='100px' width='80px'>";
}
```

When I do this, the image titles appear first, and then the images are loaded around half a second to one second afterwards. I am wondering how I can accelerate the image loading.

All images are stored in a single folder containing 70,000 images. Nearly all images are less than 50KB in size. Each image filename is of the form: id_width_height.jpg. For example, a filename might be like: 32193_80_100.jpg

I am wondering whether the bottleneck is that it takes the server some time to find the required files because there are 70,000 files in the folder. Is there a way I can accelerate this? Are there any other reasons why images are slow to load?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would inspect the image request in a network tab of Chrome/Firefox. That will answer the question of whether the lookup or the download is the critical part.
Do you have a link ?

70.000 is imho too much.. I would split the filename up and create subfolders such as: 
/htdocs/img/32193/80_100.jpg